# Is this an incorrect use of xsd:choice?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am writing a program in JavaScript that reads an XSD, creates an HTML form, and exports the form to XML.

And in order to do that I had to learn the structure of XSD but I have a doubt about `xsd:choice`.

In the example XSD file that I have been given I have this:

```
<xsd:choice>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="tagname1" type="pedidoInf:complexTypeName" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="tagname2" type="pedidoInf:otherComplexTypeName" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="tagname3" type="pedidoInf:anotherComplexTypeName" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:choice>
```

I don't know if I don't understand the `xsd:choice` correctly or this code is using nested `xsd:choice` without any reason.

Wouldn't the above code be exactly the same as:

```
<xsd:choice>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="tagname1" type="pedidoInf:complexTypeName" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="tagname2" type="pedidoInf:otherComplexTypeName" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="tagname3" type="pedidoInf:anotherComplexTypeName" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:choice>
```

Comment: Yes they are equivalent. Maybe it was auto-generated?

Comment: Might be, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title question: No, neither uses of `xsd:choice` are incorrect – they're just more complex than they have to be.

(And, yes, those two `xsd:choice` constructs would be the same.)

Both would also be equivalent to this:

```
  <xsd:choice>
    <xsd:element name="tagname1" type="pedidoInf:complexTypeName" />
    <xsd:element name="tagname2" type="pedidoInf:otherComplexTypeName" />
    <xsd:element name="tagname3" type="pedidoInf:anotherComplexTypeName" />
  </xsd:choice>
```

Comment: None of them are 'incorrect'. <xsd:choice> can contain <sequence> and vice versa. Your proposal doesn't contain <sequence> at all.

Comment: @Bryn: What's your point?  I already said that *neither uses of `xsd:choice` are incorrect*, and my proposal shows that the `xsd:sequence` versions are *more complex than they have to be* by providing a third equivalent that drops the unnecessary `xsd:sequence` constructs.

Comment: Thanks guys. Best.